# Will Thread.SpinWait be inlined when called?

Tags: c#, clr

I have following code:

```
while(flag)
{
  Thread.SpinWait(1);
}
```

following is implementation of `SpinWait` in `Rotor(sscli20\clr\src\vm\comsynchronizable.cpp)`

```
FCIMPL1(void, ThreadNative::SpinWait, int iterations)
{
    WRAPPER_CONTRACT;
    STATIC_CONTRACT_SO_TOLERANT;

    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        YieldProcessor();
}
FCIMPLEND
```

Will `Thread.SpinWait` be inlined when called?

**if not, in each loop cycle, it will spend more time on `stack operations(push and pop)` and consume more execution resource of CPU.**

**if yes, how does `clr` accomplish that while `ThreadNative::SpinWait` is implemented as standard function instruction sequence including stack operations(push and pop)?**

By testing of Eren, no inline occurs in debug mode. **Is it possible to clr optimize and produce inlined code?**

**Summary**: thanks for your answer. I wish one day clr can inline pre-compiled code by one mechanism such as MethodImplOptions.InternalCall. Then it can eliminate stack operations and spend most time on check of flag and spinning-wait(consuming less cpu resource than nop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best to try and see.  Sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true) 
        Thread.SpinWait(1);
}
```

The optimized disassembly shows:

**x86:**

```
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  mov         ecx,1 
00000008  call        6F11D3FE 
0000000d  jmp         00000003
```

**x64:**

```
00000000  sub         rsp,28h 
00000004  mov         ecx,1 
00000009  call        000000005F815434 
0000000e  jmp         0000000000000004 
00000010  add         rsp,28h 
00000014  ret
```

So there is **no inlining** in either case.

Maybe I'm missing something but I don't quite understand why you care about the stack operations as spinning the CPU consumes cycles anyway (the whole purpose is to *not* yield).

Comment: by my understand, spinwait should be used to give resource to other logical processor sharing the same one physical processor and avoid using execution resource. if not inlined, the stack operations will consume more execution resource and spinwait is not meaningful and can be replaced with an empty method.

Comment: @Vince I think you've just described 'yielding', not spinwait. The whole point of SpinWait is to keep the thread busy for a short period of time, *instead* of yielding it. So what's the point of inlining it?

Comment: If you have all logical cores pegged on a hyper-threaded CPU, then maybe yes, the spin-waiting thread could effect the other logical core. BUT I'm not sure it will be due to inlining or not -- there will be various other low level factors, which I've never had to care about (would require a deep level of analysis to determine the exact cause). Either way, you should use Thread.Sleep or a WaitHandle variant in such a case (to avoid effecting the other logical core).

Comment: @dcastro spinwait will call pause which is a delay instruction. if inline is possible, then it counld save more cpu execution resource instead spend some time on unmeaningful stack operation which competes with other logical processor on same physical processor.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I know the difference between spinwait and sleep&waithandle. spinwait will be interpreted as pause and will not yield logical processor control to other thread.

Answer (score 2):

No, the jitter is not capable of inlining pre-compiled C++ code, only managed code that started as IL.

This is entirely irrelevant for a SpinWait() call.  The point of spin-waiting is to have the processor execute code rather then paying the cost of a thread-context switch.  With the expectation that *flag* will turn *false* in 10,000 cpu cycles or less.  It doesn't matter *what* kind of code.  CALL is a fine way to execute code.

Comment: it would be more efficient if inline is possible. because stack operation will compete with other logical processor.

Comment: You are seriously missing the point, spin-waiting is often misunderstood.  Be careful, your unbounded while loop on a boolean variable is a strong code-smell.  It could only ever work correctly if that variable is declared *volatile* and the code runs on a processor with a strong memory model.  And you seriously hamper concurrency if you don't have the guarantee that the variable consistently becomes *false* in less than 10,000 cpu cycles.  YieldProcessor doesn't yield the processor, it pauses it.  Cuts down on the power usage.

Comment: Yes. I know about out-of-order and memorybarrier. we can also use Volatile.Read. Pause can save power usage against Nop and give more execution resource to other logical processor sharing same physical processor without yield time slice.